# Optimized Deployment of Keras Models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I’d like to know how to edit/deploy my Keras model (hdf5) files so that they load and run as fast as possible (using the TensorFlow backend).

Currently, after training, the *only thing I do is to set each of the net’s layers to NOT be trainable*, which helps a little bit. Here’s the code for how I save models after training:

```
model = keras.models.load_model('some_path')
for x in model.layers:
    x.trainable = False

model.save('some_path')
```

But there are more sophisticated things to do as well in a production environment (perhaps converting the model to some binary protobuf format, using some other library for inferencing, etc...)

So, I really just want to know: **when you have your model trained, what are the things to do to it to allow the fastest (a) load time and (b) inference speed, in both cpu and gpu mode**?

**Motivation:**

The motivations of this question comes from a project where I'm running my keras models inside a web server. I load the models only once at server launch, and I followed the example from https://github.com/sugyan/tensorflow-mnist1 which shows a simple restAPI example by using Flask and loading pre-trained mode. However, if you are debugging, tensorflow has issues running inside a flask project that’s in debug mode, so every time I reload the server I have to reload the models, which can take 10-20 seconds each (in hdf5 format).

Comment: I've never figured out how to get flask to run in --debug mode without tensorflow crashing either, I always have to restart the sever which means reloading models. A good answer to this question would really help!

Comment: I’m looking into tensorRt as an approach